# Using PANDA to infer gene regulatory networks without ppi

Tags: differential-expression, pandas, matlab

I'm using this tutorial (https://github.com/netZoo/netZooM/blob/master/tutorials/panda/panda.pdf) to use PANDA to infer gene regulatory networks, but without ppi values (which I've been told can be done easily using MATLAB). I replicated the codes given in the tutorial but I omitted all the portions with ppi. After doing so, I'm getting a lot of warnings and errors that makes me think I've made syntax errors in the process of taking out the ppi portions. Here's what I have:

```
addpath(genpath('path/to/netZooM'))

load("myMat.mat")
myTable = struct2table(myTable);
addpath(genpath('path/to/netZooM'));
fileparts(which('netZooM'));

exp_file = 'tests/test_data/expression.txt';
motif_file = 'tests/test_data/motifTest.txt';
panda_out = '';
lib_path = 'C:/Users/ual-laptop/Documents/bioinformatics.m/netZooM';
save_temp = '';

alpha = 0.1;
save_pairs = 0;

expressionData = readTable('expression.txt');
size(expressionData)

[TF, gene, weight] = textread(motif_file, '%s%s%f');
TFNames = unique(TF);

disp('Reading in expression data!');
fid = fopen(exp file, 'r');
headings = fget1(fid)
n = length(regexp(headings, '\t'));
frewind(fid);
Exp = textscan(fid, ['%s', repmat('%f', 1, n)], 'delimiter', '\t');
fclose(fid);
GeneNames = Exp{1};
Exp = cat(2, Exp{2:end});
[NumGenes, NumConditions] = size(Exp);
fprintf('%d genes and %d conditions!\n', NumGenes, NumConditions);
Exp = Exp';

disp('Computing coexpression network:');
GeneCoReg = Coexpression(Exp);

disp('Reading in motif data!');
[TF, gene, weight] = textread(motif_file, '%s%s%f');
TFNames = unique(TF);
NumTFs = length(TFNames);
[~,i] = ismember(TF, TFNames);
[~,j] = ismember(gene, GeneNames);
RegNet = zeros(NumTFs, NumGenes);
RegNet(sub2ind([NumTFs, NumGenes], i, j));
fprintf('%d TFs and %d edges!\n', NumTFs, length(weight));

disp('Normalizing Networks:');
RegNet = NormalizeNetwork(RegNet);
GeneCoReg = NormalizeNetwork(GeneCoReg);
TFCoop = NormalizeNetwork(TFCoop);

disp('Running PANDA algorithm:');
AgNet = PANDA(RegNet, GeneCoReg, TFCoop, alpha);

AgNet = panda_run(lib_path, exp_file, motif_file, panda_out, save_temp, alpha);

sum(AgNet, 2)
sum(Agnet, 1)
```

Are there any glaring syntax errors in my code? I'm thinking my errors could also stem from maybe cloning the github repository into the wrong place (which is a separate topic) but it's definitely possible that there are syntax errors since this is my first time doing this kind of stuff.